# Plot for discrete set of data

Tags: plotting

I was trying to make a plot of discrete set of data from two tables, the values in one table are fixed and the corresponding values in the other table are obtained from ***Mathematica*** itself by solving an equation using FindRoot command. I am having problems plotting the data from two tables. The code I wrote is as follows:

```
Table[x, {x, 0.1, 2, 0.1}]

y[_x] = Table[FindRoot[(Sqrt[1 + y[x]^2/x^2] +
    (y[x]/(2*x))^2*Log[(x/y[x])^2+Sqrt[1 + (x/y[x])^2]])*x/2 == 1, 
    {y[x], 1}], {x, 0.1, 2, 0.1}]
ListPlot[{y[x], x}]
```

The Problem being I am not getting the plot, it will be great if someone could help.Thanks.

Comment: forms of y[x] are used on both sides of the equals sign `=` which is confusing to the human reader and the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xValues = Range[0.1, 2, 0.1];

yValues = y /. 
   Table[FindRoot[(Sqrt[1 + y^2/x^2] + (y/(2*x))^2*
          Log[(x/y)^2 + Sqrt[1 + (x/y)^2]])*x/2 == 1, {y, 1}], {x, 0.1, 2, 
     0.1}];
```

[`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) with either

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{xValues, yValues}]]

ListPlot[yValues, DataRange -> {0.1, 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are seeking:

```
ListPlot[#[[1, 2]] & /@ 
  Table[FindRoot[(Sqrt[1 + z^2/x^2] + (z/(2*x))^2*
         Log[(x/z)^2 + Sqrt[1 + (x/z)^2]])*x/2 == 1, {z, 1.}], {x, 
    0.1, 2., 0.1}]]
```

[image: ListPlot Output]

If you have questions about syntax, feel free to comment upon this answer.

Comment: Thanks, but what I am actually looking for is the plot of z vs x which satisfies the given equation.

Comment: I think, I got it. The graph is showing correct z values but the corresponding x values should be from 0.1 to 2.0 in steps of 0.1, instead its showing serial number 0 to 20 for x values.